# Can "motivate" mean 'explain'; 'justify'?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

In my native language, the word corresponding to the English verb *motivate* can be used to mean something like 'explain' or 'justify'. We could for instance ask someone to 'motivate' a particular point of view, a particular choice, a particular answer etc. When I check the various dictionaries I have access to it seems that *motivate* cannot be used in this sense in English, but when I google BrE web pages for "motivate your answer", I nevertheless get a number of hits that seem to support this use also in English – for instance:

> Use the specific data given above to motivate your answer

> If you wish, please motivate your answer (max. 1000 characters)

> Describe the objective data you would collect from patient T and motivate your answer.

So, is it, after all, possible to use *motivate* in this sense in English, or are the above examples just bad English? If it is possible, would it also be possible to use a modified participle of this verb as a premodifier in a NP, as in *well-motivated choices* and *well-motivated answers*? If not, what could I use instead?

Thank you!

Comment: South Africa English: ​motivate something (South African English, formal) to give reasons for something that you have stated
Please motivate your answer to question 5. Oxford Learners Dictionary.....

Comment: This is very interesting - this meaning of *motivate* is completely unknown in US English (as far as I am aware) but it seems like it has currency in other dialects.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is used in the UK by some people in that sense. I think it is a relatively recent arrival in our linguistic landscape though so perhaps it is a borrowing from other dialects or even a direct translation from another language like Spanish *motivar* for instance. That might explain it poor showing in dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you! It's particularly interesting that it's gaining ground in the UK but not in the US though, if it's a Spanish borrowing, seeing that AmE would probably be more susceptible to Spanish influence than BrE.

Comment: @Helen it may come from somewhere else but I happen to know that word in Spanish.

Comment: My Spanish is not great, but it's also possible that this sense of *motivar* is more of a *castellano*, i.e. "Spain Spanish" usage, which might explain it: [the Real Academia Española dictionary includes the definition and example](https://dle.rae.es/motivar?m=form) "Dar o explicar la razón o motivo que se ha tenido para hacer algo. *Debes motivar la respuesta.*"; while the [Diccionario del español de México definition doesn't](https://dem.colmex.mx/Ver/motivar);  US English is more influenced by Latin American Spanish than Spain Spanish.

Comment: @stangdon Interesting! Yes, that would explain it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid to say that it would be bad English.

*Motivate* does not mean *explain* or *justify*. It is that simple.

Comment: Thank you – that's what I thought as well, but Lambie's comment to my question, and mdewey's answer seem to support its use in (at least) South African English and BrE. Interesting indeed. I take it you (Patriot) are from the States?